# scapy sniff function doesnt seem to work in moniter mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, scapy, sniffing

I'm trying to write a packet sniffer that will take an interface and a regex expresion as optional parameter and search the sniffed packets for matches, but it seems to not be able to sniff packets at all, The whole code is:

```py
#!/home/khaled/PycharmProjects/networking/venv/bin/python3
# A regular expresion finder

from scapy.all import *
import re
import os
import argparse
import subprocess
import sys

def test(num):
    num = num.sprintf('%Raw.load%')
    print("Packet Data: {}".format(num))
    res = re.findall("TESTING", num)


def parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="command -i <interface>",
                                     description="Listen for incoming traffic on specified interface for specified"
                                                 "regex expresion")
    parser.add_argument("-i", help="The interface to listen on", dest="interface", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-r", help="regex expresion to look for", dest="regex", required=False, default=False)
    env = parser.parse_args()
    global interface
    global regex
    interface = env.interface
    regex = env.regex

def start_sniff(interface):
    # Check if a
    print(conf.iface)
    print("[+] Started Sniffing For regex in HTTP data at interface {}".format(interface))
    sniff(prn=test, filter="tcp", iface=interface, count=0, monitor=True)


def start_moniter_interface(iface):

    try:
        # subprocess.run(['airmon-ng', "check", "kill"], check=True)
        rslt = subprocess.run(["airmon-ng", "start", iface], check=True, capture_output=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("[+] Error Has Occurred when putting Interface in monitor mode {}".format(e.stderr))
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print("[+] Started interface in moniter mode")
        interface_name = re.findall("wlp[0-9a-z]+mon", rslt.stdout.decode("utf-8"))[0]
        print("[+] Found interface Name is {}".format(interface_name))
        if interface_name:  # Found interface name
            return interface_name
        else:               # Else Run iwconfig
            # nfig manually
            print("Unable to determine interface name")
            print("Run iwconfig and rerun script with new interface name")
            sys.exit(1)


def main():
    parser()

    if os.getuid() != 0:    # Not running as root run with sudo
        print("Error Need to run script as root, run with sudo")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:   # running as root
        result = subprocess.run(["iwconfig", interface], capture_output=True, check=True)
        if "mode:moniter" in result.stdout.decode("utf-8").lower(): # Check Moniter mode
            start_sniff(interface)
        else:   # Else start Interface in moniter mode then sniff for packets
            moniter_interface = start_moniter_interface(interface)
            start_sniff(moniter_interface)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It uses `airmon` to put network card in monitor mode then use `iwconfig` to grab name of card after being put in monitor mode. The regular expression passed by user is ignored for now. The `test` function doesn't seem to be called at all which I dont know why since `sniff` function seems to work when wireless card is in `managed` mode. It just hang at doing nothing

```
[+] Started Sniffing For regex in HTTP data at interface wlp2s0mon
```

sniff function called as:

```
    sniff(prn=card_type, filter="tcp", iface=interface, count=0, monitor=True)
```

also running `iwconfig` shows that network card is in monitor mode.

Comment: What's your OS. Check that your card also supports monitor mode.

Comment: @Cukic0d I'm running linux (ubuntu 20.0) and yes my card does support monitor mode as ```iwconfig``` says it's in monitor mode also wire-shark does capture packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering for tcp on kernel level using BPF filter. I bet that you sniff from a WPA2 protected network, meaning that payload in 802.11 (Wi-Fi) frame is encrypted, so you can't actually take a look inside a frame. I suggest trying to sniff without monitor mode at all, so you capture regular 802.3 Ethernet frames and not raw 802.11 with as I mentioned payload encrypted.

Comment: ohh I didn't thought in that at all. thank's alot but is there a way in scapy to use monitor mode and only decrypt my own network traffic(enter the WIFI password) so that I can sniff other clients traffic or WPA2 use different keys for different connected clients since I'm not familiar with WPA2 encryption scheme.

Comment: If you want to decrypt frames of the fly (live decryption/parsing) then I'm not sure how to do this trick. But if you'll be alright with looking for tcp from an offline pcap then take a look at [this thread](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/24249/decrypt-wpa-with-tshark) with explanation on how to decrypt WPA protected frames using `tshark` given that you know the passphrase for a Wi-Fi network. Once pcap you gathered is decrypted you can parse it with scapy for payload specific fields like TCP.